# Zend Framework 2: How to add additional fields to ZfcUser's register form?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I installed *ZfcUser* and added first_name/last_name columns to my user table.

How do I override the registration form and add first_name/last_name to the view?

I know how to override views. But I'm guessing that I also need to either override the User controller or the User form. And that's where I'm stuck - I don't know how to override Controllers/Forms.

I already have created my own User module which I use for overriding.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that in ZfcUser\Form\Register have a event call in __construct() method which is:

```
        $this->getEventManager()->trigger('init', $this);
```

So you could extends Register form and add your first_name/last_name elements by

```
class MyForm extends ZfcUser\Form\Register {
    public function init(){
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'first_name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'First Name',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'text'
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'last_name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Last Name',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'text'
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

Then you could add your form as a service in Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'myform' => function ($sm) {
                $form = new MyForm(null, $options);
                return $form;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

Finally, as you said, you also need to output the first_name/last_name input elements to the view.

Comment: This deals with extending the form, I have a blog post that adds how to store what you extend in case it helps you http://circlical.com/blog/2013/4/1/l5wftnf3p7oks5561bohmb9vkpasp6

Comment: So how u render form fields with this example ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can also write your own entity class like the one in ZfcUser\Entity\User.php and then make sure you edit the Zfcuser config.

I like AlloVince's answer and I am actually going to try it out. The SaaS app I am working on will have dynamic forms so I am going to test his now